# Character Encoding error when copying double quotes from word or other source

Tags: mysql, jsp, character-encoding

I am using JSP servlets and have a mysql database. I have an input field "Introduction". The error is when a user copy pastes a para from word then the character "(double quotes) is entered as ? in my table but only when the character is copied from a word or some other source. Also, if a user copies two paragraph's with spaces in between then a buggy character enters my sql table and the JS which is trying to load the introduction in my jsp page fails. i have also attached the screenshot for this. Please help me how can i resolve this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

MicroSoft, in its infinite wisdom, decided to have non-standard double quotes -- a left version and a right version.  But that should be fixable, since those quotes do exist somewhere in the huge world of utf8 characters.

However, the data from your 'copy' was probably not copied in utf8 encoding.  Since is is unclear how that is being done, we can't give you complete details on fixing it.

The "best" plan is to establish "utf8" at all stages of data/client/server/database/table/column/etc.

The quick-and-dirty fix is to replace the funny quotes with ascii quotes.

Comment: Hi rick, i have utf8 encoding evrywhere : JSP(<meta charset="utf8">), database,table,column. Then also, when i copy ' " ' from word file , it does not reach the backend (I debugged and saw). The character is not visible at the backened and that is the reason the mysql puts " ? " instead.

Comment: The connection needs to establish utf8; the column needs to be `CHARACTER SET utf8`; the <meta> tag needs to be there (as you have it).  Did the string get truncated?  Or was the naughty character replaced by "?" and the rest of the string is intact?